# Git error building trees when clear cache

Tags: php, git, yii2

I'm new to Git. i have everything worked before. but the problem came when i try to follow some tutorials regarding .gitignore not woking. Finally i used git clearcache but now i'm getting other error

I used :

```
git add .

git commit -m "testing gitignore"

git push origin arabic
```

Error :

```
You have both vendor/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput and vendor/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/.github/CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
You have both vendor/kartik-v/dependent-dropdown and vendor/kartik-v/dependent-dropdown/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
You have both vendor/kartik-v/strength-meter and vendor/kartik-v/strength-meter/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
You have both vendor/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base and vendor/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
You have both vendor/kartik-v/yii2-password and vendor/kartik-v/yii2-password/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
You have both vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker and vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
You have both vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop and vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
You have both vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput and vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
You have both vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 and vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2/.github/CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
You have both vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead and vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md
...
error: Error building trees
```

How i can fix this error ?

I'm unable to push to my repository now.

Comment: Why you mention Github?

Comment: Sorry. Updated Question

Answer (score 1):

`git clearcache` is not a Git command.  (Where did you get it?)

The error message suggests that whatever this `git clearcache` program is, it damaged Git's index.  If you don't mind losing the effect of your `git add .`, you can re-build the index, then re-do the `git add`, using these basic shell commands:

```
rm .git/index
git reset
git add .
```

(this assumes you are at the top level of your repository, so that `.git/index` names Git's index file).  Removing the file and running `git reset` rebuilds the index from the current commit, destroying the effect of all previous `git add` and/or `git rm` commands.

If `git clearcache` contains such commands, this will also undo *its* operations, but it looks like that may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where the directory on windows was in read-only mode

[image]

Click properties

[image]

Then if read-only is selected - de-select it and hit apply or ok. Next, you should close your IDE and then re-open it and try to make a new commit.